# 2 Java classes with the same Content (functions, variables etc.)

Tags: java, class

Say that the user gives you a phone number (as an object of the class PhoneNumber or a subclass of it) which he first states if it's a Mobile Phone or a House Phone. In the main program you should be able to know (way afterwards) if it refers to a Mobile Phone or to a House Phone.

And here's what you can't do:

1. You can't check the numbers to find out because the user is actually able to give any number he wants (he could give 9123 for a House Phone).
2. You can't make any variable (in the classes or in the main Program) that states the answer.

Should you make two different classes that extend the class PhoneNumber and have the exact same content (in my example they are actually empty, but in my real problem they're not)? If you do so you can make objects of those classes and use **instanceof** in the main program, but I wonder if there's another solution, one that seems better to the eye.

EDIT: What seems wrong to me are the 2 classes with the same contents, not instanceof, because we actually only know that for figuring out an object's class.

Example:

```
public class PhoneNumber{
     private int Number;

     public PhoneNumber(int Number){
          this.Number = Number;
     }
}

public class Mobile extends PhoneNumber{}

public class HousePhone extends PhoneNumber{}
```

Comment: Thanks in advance and sorry for any mistakes, this is my first question

Comment: "You can't make any variable (in the classes or in the main Program) that states the answer." <- Why not?

Comment: You could instead extend `PhoneNumber` once and add an enum to indicate what type of number it is eg: `public enum PhoneNumber.PhoneType {MOBILE, HOME}` and store a member of that.

Comment: OH GOD SPIDERS the exact variables are stated

Comment: @CollinD We are not supposed to use enum yet

Comment: @BasilKaratzas That's quite the arbitrary coding puzzle you have there. Please provide the full "rules" of your homework.

Comment: @CollinD I am so sorry I didn't see your comment earlier. I currently follow  what we've been tought in my class. Until now every exercise stated specifically the variables every class must have and had no other. Because my problem has a catalog of phone numbers (in array form), I wanted to follow 2 ways and see what's best. In the first I'll make a second array with Strings stating the class of each phone number. In the second I followed as above, not making any more variables in the main class. I will show both to my teacher and ask what he prefers. I think he'll say the 2nd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you **can't create** any **variable** in the main program, your options are obviously **limited**.

You could use OOP concepts to solve this problem as you have attempted. And you don't need to duplicate the contents since inheriting from the same parent which already has all that content would automatically grant them access to the content. This includes all properties and fields except those specified as private. To solve this, you could make those properties protected.

The following should work for you:

```
public abstract class PhoneNumber
{
    private int Number;


    public PhoneNumber(int Number)
    {
       this.Number = Number;
    }

    protected int getNumber()
    {
        return Number;
    }

    public void doSmthnWithNumber();
}

public class Mobile extends PhoneNumber
{
    @Override
    public void doSmthnWithNumber()
    {
        int Number = getNumber();
        // Do whatever you want with mobile numbers
    }
}

public class HousePhone extends PhoneNumber
{
    @Override
    public void doSmthnWithNumber()
    {
        int Number = getNumber();
       // Do whatever you want with HousePhone numbers
    }
}
```

So with this, you know that there is no redundancy in your code, you are not repeating yourself and you are following SOLID principles. Makes it easier on the eye and better for other devs to understand you.
Also you can make changes to PhoneNumber and it will reflect in the child classes.

Hope I have been able to solve your problems.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Sounds like a good idea, I will ask my teacher for it

Comment: @staa99 i guess you forgot to add keyword *`abstract`* in the method signature.  `public void doSmthnWithNumber();`

Comment: You are right, I forgot to add abstract. Thanks for pointing it out for me.

Comment: @BasilKaratzas if you like my solution, you can upvote my answer and accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: @staa99 I can't upvote due to my reputation (just joined in this community). After some thought I think your answer was the most helpful. Sorry for choosing a correct answer after so much time

Comment: @BasilKaratzas I feel great to find that my answer helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make any variable (in the classes or in the main Program) that states the answer. But you can make a method to get the type. In your classes `Mobile` and `HousePhone` create a method `getPhoneType` that return an `enum` of some kind. The `getPhoneType` method should be abstract method in base class.

I think this better than `instanceof`.

Comment: My problem is those 2 classes with the exact same content. I wonder if it is shown as something bad for my program. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

Alternate to `instanceof`, you could use `isAssignableFrom` e.g.

```
    PhoneNumber phoneNum = new Mobile(123);

    if (phoneNum.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Mobile.class)) {
        Mobile mobile = (Mobile) phoneNum;
    } else {
        HousePhone housePhone = (HousePhone) phoneNum;
    }
```

Comment: But I would still have to create those 2 same classes right?. Thanks for answering

Comment: Whats better about this solution? `isAssignableFrom` is a complete overkill if all you want is `instanceof`, less verbose on what the code does and more complicated without any obvious benefits. You could go for `isInstance` instead, which is totally sufficient for this purpose.

Comment: Maybe I didn't write that good. Instanceof is actually the only method we know in my class that can answer you if an object belongs to a specific class. What seems a bit off to me are those 2 classes that have the same variables, functions and constructors (my real problem is of course much bigger than this)